# Redirect to value from select list

Tags: rules, redirection

I'm having a problem redirecting a user on login. I have a user field `field_redirect_field`, that is a **select list (text)**.

I want to have a list of links of my site and the user can select in a list where he redirects after logging in. (I create the list manually)

this is an example of my values list:

> user/me/edit|me

The key is **user/me/edit** and the label is **me**. Now the problem is in my rule I have a redirect to the field **[account:field_redirect_field]**. But he redirects to the label and not to the key.

This is what I've tried:

I've tried to change the display of the redirect field by going to **Manage Display** and set the redirect field to show the **Key** instead of the label. But the strange thing is that he still shows the value when I want to edit a user.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Manage Display**, on "CUSTOM DISPLAY SETTINGS" enable the checkbox "Token"